# How can I generate Lotus Notes (8.5) emails from external RSS feeds?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I would like to have a Lotus Notes email auto-generated and sent to a specific Lotus Notes account whenever new items are detected via an RSS feed subscribed to on the UI sidebar. Any and all suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As the RSS feed reader in the sidebar is an "as is" component you can't modify, what you would like to have is not doable.

You would have to write a program for that (Notes Agent, Perl Script, ...).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way to have Domino ingest RSS feed items without using the Lotus Notes sidebar i.e. being a server-side process rather than using the client UI? If so, would it then be possible to create an Agent to react to additions to the Domino database containing newly-added feed items (which database would they go into?) and generate the emails that way?

Comment: Yes, there are Domino applications that run on a Domino server and ingest RSS feeds into NSF files.  There's one called "Studio Blog Reader" posted as open source on OpenNTF. There's also one available from www.madicon.de, but it's not freeware.

And I wrote one myself and intended to release it as open source years ago, but never got around to it.  It's Windows-only due to its dependence on WinHTTP. It has Notes and web UI's and it can also generate a single RSS feed that consolidates the feeds it pulls in. I would be willing to share it, but I cannot offer any support.

Comment: Shane - I will post my old template somewhere and add a link.